# iOS8 with storyboard and autolayout how to replace a UIView with it's clone in the view hierarchy?

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios8, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have a web view embedded into a UIViewController and would like to reset it's browsing history. One way I can think of doing that is by removing the web view and replacing it with a new web view.

**How can I take a UIView out of the view hierarchy, remember it's constraints and put in another view in its place and apply previous constraints?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a better way than removing the view, anyhow for removing the view and save the constraints all you need to do is to save the array constraints.

```
   NSArray *constraintsArray = self.webView.constraints;
   [self.webView removeFromSuperview];
   [self.view addSubview:newWebView];
   [newWebView addConstraints:constraintsArray];
   [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```